# Smooth input data without using arrays or dynamic allocation

Tags: c, signal-processing, moving-average

I'm trying to smooth input data (real positive) without using arrays or dynamic allocation. Is it possible?

The end condition is when the user enters a negative number. For example:

```
 input: 1 2 3 4 5 -1
output: 1.5 2 3 4 4.5
```

Comment: Shotgunning your post with a bunch of language flags won't really help when what you're really asking is an algorithmic question. I've no idea what sort of filtering you had in mind, or why, but there are certainly filters that don't need the entire signal history in order to function (the correct technical term escapes me. A Kalman filter is an example of this type).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I've removed the Java and C++ tags as this question appears to relate only to C.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a moving average. In it's simplest form

```
const int smooth_factor = 3; // the higher the value the more smooth it is.
int samples = 0;
int total = 0;         // make long or long long if danger of overflow.

int smoothed(int new_sample)
{
   if (samples == smooth_factor)
   {
      total -= total / smooth_factor;
      samples -= 1;
   }
   total += new_sample;
   samples += 1;
   return total / samples;
}
```

In practice you would probably make it more efficient by using a power of two smooth_factor and using shift operation instead of division by smooth_factor. 
You can also get rid of the if statement if you are willing to pre-seed total and num samples.

```
const int smooth_factor = 16; // the higher the value the more smooth it is.
int total = 129;              // e.g. 129 = sum of first 16 samples

int smoothed(int new_sample)
{
      total -= total >> 4;
      total += new_sample;
      return total >> 4;
}
```

If you are smoothing over many values then you can remove one of the shifts without significant effect (but I will leave that as an exercise).

Comment: This is not a moving average. Moving average requires storage for the N previous samples with the optimization, that one can store the previous SUM, add the incoming sample and subtract the last sample in the "sliding window". More over, the sliding window can be implemented as circular buffer, preferably of size 2^n, even though the size of the window was smaller.

Comment: @Dipstick Thank you for your simple yet elegant solution! Exactly what I've been looking for.:-)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "can I declare an undefined number of variables without using arrays or dynamic allocation?", the answer is no.

Comment: You, sir, are the [enemy of imagination](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0al0xeCVCMk)!  *(Did I mention the imagination is a dying animal?)*  :-)

Comment: I didn't meant there wasn't any other solution, (like the one that proposed Dipstick). But the OP didn't seem to have tried a lot of things, so I didn't want to post one for just giving him some code he didn't try to type himself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "filter" a signal without memory. Period.

With n slots of memory one can achieve either FIR filter, or IIR filter (or a combination of both).

If one doesn't like the array notation `a[5],b[5]` the rules can be bent by declaring an array of individual variables, like.

```
 static a0=0,a1=0,a2=0,a3=0,   b0=0,b1=0,b2=0,b3=0;

 output = b3* B3 + b2*B2 + b1*B1 + b0* B0; // where B0..B3 are constant coefficients
 b3=b2;b2=b1;b1=b0; b0=new_sample;  // This is FIR filter (Finite impulse response)

 a0=output;
 output += a3*A3 + a2*A2 + a1*A1;   // and this implements an IIR filter
 a3=a2;a2=a1;a1=a0;                 // Infinite impulse response
```

Still the concept of array persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you can save state in a few variables or registers instead of array elements, then you can use an IIR (or recursive) filter for real-time processing.  Search for DSP biquad filters, which are IIR filters which require only 4 state variables when processing data sample-by-sample.

Note that IIR filters will incur some frequency-dependent non-linear phase delay.  The "smoothed" output won't come out until some number of samples after the corresponding input and may be skewed in shape.